# Android NDK: jnix jar not loading

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have placed jnix.jar file in libs folder and added to build path as well. But I am receiving following crash when I try to load the library with System.loadLibrary("jnix"). it is listed in Referenced Libraries though.

```
03-07 22:04:24.822: E/streamer(8746): Couldn't load jnix: findLibrary returned null
03-07 22:04:24.822: E/streamer(8746): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load jnix: findLibrary returned null
03-07 22:04:24.822: E/streamer(8746):   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
03-07 22:04:24.822: E/streamer(8746):   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
03-07 22:04:24.822: E/streamer(8746):   at ob.android.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:38)
03-07 22:04:24.822: E/streamer(8746):   at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-07 22:04:24.822: E/streamer(8746):   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
03-07 22:04:24.822: E/streamer(8746):   at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1039)
03-07 22:04:24.822: E/streamer(8746):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
03-07 22:04:24.822: E/streamer(8746):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
03-07 22:04:24.822: E/streamer(8746):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
03-07 22:04:24.822: E/streamer(8746):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
03-07 22:04:24.822: E/streamer(8746):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-07 22:04:24.822: E/streamer(8746):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
03-07 22:04:24.822: E/streamer(8746):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
03-07 22:04:24.822: E/streamer(8746):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 22:04:24.822: E/streamer(8746):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-07 22:04:24.822: E/streamer(8746):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-07 22:04:24.822: E/streamer(8746):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-07 22:04:24.822: E/streamer(8746):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-07 22:04:24.822: W/dalvikvm(8746): Exception Ljava/lang/RuntimeException; thrown while initializing Lob/android/MainActivity;
03-07 22:04:24.822: W/dalvikvm(8746): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lob/android/MainActivity;)
03-07 22:04:24.822: D/AndroidRuntime(8746): Shutting down VM
03-07 22:04:24.822: W/dalvikvm(8746): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40abe228)
03-07 22:04:24.862: E/AndroidRuntime(8746): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 22:04:24.862: E/AndroidRuntime(8746): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
03-07 22:04:24.862: E/AndroidRuntime(8746):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-07 22:04:24.862: E/AndroidRuntime(8746):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
03-07 22:04:24.862: E/AndroidRuntime(8746):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1039)
03-07 22:04:24.862: E/AndroidRuntime(8746):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
03-07 22:04:24.862: E/AndroidRuntime(8746):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
03-07 22:04:24.862: E/AndroidRuntime(8746):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
03-07 22:04:24.862: E/AndroidRuntime(8746):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
03-07 22:04:24.862: E/AndroidRuntime(8746):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-07 22:04:24.862: E/AndroidRuntime(8746):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
03-07 22:04:24.862: E/AndroidRuntime(8746):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
03-07 22:04:24.862: E/AndroidRuntime(8746):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 22:04:24.862: E/AndroidRuntime(8746):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-07 22:04:24.862: E/AndroidRuntime(8746):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-07 22:04:24.862: E/AndroidRuntime(8746):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-07 22:04:24.862: E/AndroidRuntime(8746):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-07 22:04:24.862: E/AndroidRuntime(8746): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load jnix: findLibrary returned null
03-07 22:04:24.862: E/AndroidRuntime(8746):     at ob.android.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:47)
03-07 22:04:24.862: E/AndroidRuntime(8746):     ... 15 more
03-07 22:04:24.862: E/AndroidRuntime(8746): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load jnix: findLibrary returned null
03-07 22:04:24.862: E/AndroidRuntime(8746):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
03-07 22:04:24.862: E/AndroidRuntime(8746):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
03-07 22:04:24.862: E/AndroidRuntime(8746):     at ob.android.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:38)
03-07 22:04:24.862: E/AndroidRuntime(8746):     ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 0):

loadLibrary() is for native code, which is usually compiled C or C++. Jar is a Java library, you can use such libraries in Android but these will be compiled into your Java code. Note that Android runs a different JVM and its runtime environment is only partially compatible with JRE.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, System.loadLibrary() is for native code. Provided that your jar file is correctly added to your build path, you should be able to just import the classes like normal.

For example, if the class you want to use from the jar file was in the package com.jnixpackage and the class name was JnixClass, you could import it by adding

```
import com.jnixpackage.JnixClass;
```

to the top of your java file.